# insert into List using ID java

Tags: java

Currently I have a method to insert **behaviors** into a List from another class called **Aptitude**. Behaviors have an ID and I want to insert the next behavior created into the list with the next available ID not present in the whole List.
I'm doing it like this:

```
public Behavior addBehavior(BehaviorDto behaviorDto, String aptitudeId) {
    Aptitude aptitude;
    aptitude = findById(aptitudeId);
    List<Behavior> behaviors = aptitude.getBehaviors();
    int nextId = -1;
    boolean flag;
    for (int i = 1; i <= behaviors.size() + 1; i++) {
        flag = true;
        for (Behavior behavior1 : behaviors) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(behavior1.getId()) == i) {
                flag = false;
                continue;
            }

        }
        if (flag) {
            nextId = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```

But I remember being told that there was a way to optimize and not need to use a **flag** variable.

How can I improve this code?

### edit

the rest of the method:

```
Behavior behavior = new Behavior(String.valueOf(nextId), behaviorDto.getEn(), behaviorDto.getEs());
behavior.setId(String.valueOf(nextId));
aptitude.addBehavior(behavior);
updateAptitude(aptitude);
return behavior;
```

Comment: Could you show the rest of addBehavior method ?

Comment: How about sorting the list by id, then traverse until an entry's id+1 != next entry's id?

Comment: Or use a Map to store mappings of id's to behavior, or use a Set as secondary store for all id's already used.

Comment: A clean solution might be to make your Behaviour implement the interface Comparable and use the compareTo-method for sorting by id as described in the java api documentation. When you get a list, just sort it by using Collections.sort and after that, add an element by using the size of the list +2 (as you seem to start by id=1 with your algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move id generation to Behavior's constructor:

```
class Behavior {
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public Behavior(BehaviorDto behaviorDto) {
        \\other constructor things
        this.id = counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

After this be done, you can just do:

```
public Behavior addBehavior(BehaviorDto behaviorDto, String aptitudeId) {
    Aptitude aptitude;
    aptitude = findById(aptitudeId);
    List<Behavior> behaviors = aptitude.getBehaviors();
    Behavior newBehavior = new Behavior(behaviorDto);
    behaviors.add(newBehavior);
    return newBehavior;
}
```

Comment: hadn't considered this, but wouldn't this make the counter increase for Behaviors of diferent Aptitudes?. i mean 2 diferent List<Behavior> would have completely diferent IDs? or is that something fixed with the AtomicInteger atribute?

Comment: yes, 2 diferent List<Behavior> would have completely diferent IDs. AtomicInteger is for mulrithreading only. If you use only one thread, it can be changed to: private static int counter; and in constructor: this.id = ++counter;

Answer (score 1):

I would expect `Aptitude` to 'know' the next available behavior id *(Object Oriented)*.

```
public Behavior addBehavior(BehaviorDto behaviorDto, String aptitudeId) {
    Aptitude aptitude = findById(aptitudeId);
    List<Behavior> behaviors = aptitude.getBehaviors();
    int nextId = aptitude.getNextBehaviorId()

    // ...
}
```